# Macro to print function entry and exit trace

Tags: c++, function, macros, trace

I'm trying to debug an issue and I would like to print the traces for entry and exit/leave of every function so that I can trace the flow of sequence.
A macro to print the function entry and exit/leave trace can be written.
I know I should create a class whose constructor should record entry and desctructor should record exit/leave of the function. But I'm not clear how exactly it should be implemented. Any suggestions would be helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: You're asking for code or tips 'n pointers? Why not use gdb?

Comment: I don't see how adding 'function entered' and 'function exit' would help you debug an issue. If you have trouble following the "flow of sequence", then your program probably needs to be refactored. It would be faster to read a tutorial on GDB than writing an ad hoc macro to automatically trace functions.

Comment: Add entry and exit trace will let me isolate the part of the code where something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define LOG_CALL tracer_t _token(__func__)
struct tracer_t {
    char const* fname;
    tracer_t(char const* fname_): fname(fname_) { printin(fname); }
    ~tracer_t() { printout(fname); }
}

void myfunc() { LOG_CALL;
    // test function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several logging frameworks for C++ that help do this sort of thing. I like log4cplus.